# Refreshed all my Magento2 cache and website is down now

Tags: magento2, cache, exception

I just used all those functions:

> Flush Magento Cache
>
> Flush Cache Sm Module
>
> Flush Catalog Images Cache
>
> Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache
>
> Flush Static Files Cache

And refreshed all my files. After that, when I enter my website I recieved this on the front page:

```
 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/pub/static/frontend/Sm/lovefashion/ro_RO/css/config_1.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/ecustock.ro/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/Sm/lovefashion/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml on line 92
```

with 36 more errors after  that

Comment: Are you in production mode? Enter command `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show` to see the result.

Comment: Run following command : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and give required permession for pub and var folders

Comment: It is a permission issue may be

Comment: This server is powered by Plesk. Log in by browsing
https://188.213.20.104:8443/

You can log in as user 'root' or 'admin'. To log in as 'admin', use the 'plesk login' command.
Use the 'plesk' command to manage the server. Run 'plesk help' for more info.

[root@server ~]# php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Could not open input file: bin/magento
[root@server ~]#

Comment: I can't use php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

Comment: You need to run that command from your website root

Comment: How can i do that? From where? I use ""cd /"" and i still get the same error  Could not open input file: bin/magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the to developer mode using below

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Setup using below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Compile using belwo command. this will take long time.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile


php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I opened the SSH console and typed:

cd /
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

but I get this error:
Could not open input file: bin/magento

Comment: goto your Magento root folder in SSH and paste or type '`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: I accesed root server using "cd /" and the command is still not working...

Comment: Please go to your magento installed folder that will in `www` like this `[stagingalainadm@xxx.xxx.xx.xx www]` you might have to do `cd www` then use commands. you don't have go `cd/ php bin` etc. or update your question with your current director screenshot.

Comment: Here it's the screen with the SSH commands and errors: https://imgur.com/a/OLkjyG4     -> in the screen you can also see the directory where magento is installed. If you want to see all the errors i get, this is the website: http://www.ecustock.ro/

Comment: Goto `cd httpdocs` and try the Commands this will work

Comment: [root@server /]# cd httpdocs
-bash: cd: httpdocs: No such file or directory
[root@server /]#
---> not working, i tried it also in the screenshot... what to do?

Comment: Do you know your user created for this site..? you need to login with same details u use fro Cpanel for this site in putty also. then you will be in 'root'. but with site user name.

Comment: Don't use `root` login use Site user login instead. use the same credentials u used in `Filezilla`

Comment: -bash-4.2$ cd httpdocs
-bash-4.2$ php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html-bash-4.2$

Comment: Please check if you are getting same list of directory in `putty` using `$ dir` then commands will work.

Comment: This is what i get using $ dir command in putty https://imgur.com/a/s7gHmv6

Comment: still this command  `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` is not working for you .? add me skype: jyothibabuolive